# org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.12.3: not found

Tags: scala, sbt

I have fought with that for several days but still no luck :(
Tried to add some "resolvers" etc. But I have no any right direction to move along.
Looks like no org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.12.3
but I can access http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.3/ivys/ivy.xml
using my browser (so artifact is available).

I'm behind the proxy server btw, but I have a feeling that it doesn't matter.

Here is a log:

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\proj\blogger-example\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/proj/blogger-example/project/}default-265363...
[info] Resolving com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.12.3 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.12.3
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\oabakumov\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.12.3\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.3/sbt-0.12.3.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.3/sbt-0.12.3.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.2 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.12.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.12.3: not found
```

My `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "blogger-example"
version := "1.0"
```

My `project\plugins.sbt` file:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.4.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the proxy is set also correctly in the shell (or command prompt).

E.g on a windows 7 machine, set the following environment variable

HTTP_PROXY = myproxy.com:1234

Comment: thank you all. proxy has ruined my build. i really hate them all.

Answer (score 0):

I opened my update.log file (.sbt\boot directory) today. And detailed log helped me to dig in correct direction. I had HTTP 403 error (meant "you has no access to that resource"). So - the question was in my environment settings (SBT settings - sbtconfig.txt).

So... My advice - when nothing clear with your build - go to the log file.