# Why does sbt report "Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.11"?

Tags: scala, sbt

In a Scala project I updated the `build.properties` from **0.13.8** to **0.13.11**. That "broke" sbt as it does not start anymore, i.e. it cannot download the 0.13.11 jars?! sbt prints a list of tried repo's, but the `repo.typesafe.com` was not one of them.

My local installed sbt is **0.13.8**.

For some reason the `scala-sbt` jars are not available anymore in Typesafe's Bintray. Largest version there is 0.13.9.

I know the place to get it is https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, but how do I tell sbt to use this repo?

I have already tried:

- adding a resolver to `plugins.sbt`
- adding a resolver to `build.sbt`
- adding the repo to `.sbt/repositories`

but I cannot get it working.

How to tell sbt where to get binaries?

Comment: You shouldn't need an extra resolver. Perhaps it's just a temporary network problem? Have you checked the update.log like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675444/org-scala-sbtsbt0-12-3-not-found ?

Comment: If you're behind a proxy, then this might help: [SBT 0.13.11 cannot download dependencies behind a proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440794/sbt-0-13-11-cannot-download-dependencies-behind-a-proxy)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Make sure that you're using sbt (launcher) that's at the same version of higher than the version used in your project.

   Execute `sbt about` in an empty directory and find `[info] This is sbt X.Y.X`.
2. Make sure that you don't use `~/.sbt/repositories` file that sets up the repositories used to resolve artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

try to set your https proxy Information into http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort. This solved it for me.